# Gaps (misinterpreting perhaps) between chi square sig and Cramer’s v

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, cramers-v

I did chi square test for independence and Cramer’s V test.
I’m having problems with interpret the results.
I checked if there is a connection between gender and dropping out of school (in SPSS).
My H1 assumption is of course that there is a connection.
In the chi square test, under significance it showed <.001 - which I interpreted as significant results
However, in Cramer’s V value I got .066 - which I interpreted as weak connection.

Is it possible or am I misunderstanding the results?
How can chi point that there’s significant connection between the variables but in the same time it’s weak also?

Pls help me I need to get a final project at this course

Thank you so much
[image]